# .Net Encrypt XML stream with AES and 128 bit Initialization vector

Tags: .net, vb.net, encryption, aes, rsa

I am working on a project where I am posting to a web service via XML stream. In this case the provider is requesting that the routing xml be encrypted with Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) in Cipher Block Chaining (CBC) mode with a 128 bit initialization vector. I am coding in VB.Net and from what I can tell I have met all of their encryption requirements, but I keep getting an "Invalid Routing Input encryption" error response when I submit the post. I have not done much with encryption so I was hoping that someone with some encryption experience could help me out here. Is it failing because I am not prefixing the IV correctly? Is there a standard way in AES to merge IV to the cipher data? Or is there a problem with how I am doing the encryption itself? I’ve been stuck here for awhile and tried a couple different ways of encrypting but have not had success. Listed below is my code and a summary of the encryption requirements.

1. Generate a symmetric key using Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) in Cipher Block Chaining (CBC) mode with a 128 bit initialization vector [AES] algorithm. Do not use a zero byte initialization vector.
2. Encrypt the valid Routing Input xml document using the AES symmetric key. Prefix the resulting cipher text with the 128 bit initialization vector. (It is not recommended to use an initialization vector with all 0 bytes.)
3. Base64 encode the initialization vector and the encrypted Routing Input xml document.
4. Build the ENCRYPTED_RI xml element using the base64 encoded initialization vector and encrypted Routing Input xml document.
5. Generate SHA1 hash for the plaintext Routing Input xml document.
6. Concatenate the SHA1 hash of the plaintext Routing Input xml document and AES symmetric key. (SHA1 hash + AES symmetric key)
7. Encrypt the concatenated result using the public key and RSA version 1.5 algorithm [RFC 2437].
8. Base64 encode the encrypted concatenated result.
9. Build the ENCRYPTED_KEY xml element using the base64 encoded encrypted concatenated result.

Here is my code:

```
Sub CreateEncryptionXML()
    '############
    '## CREATE AES KEY AND IV
    '############
    Dim SymKey() As Byte
    Dim IV() As Byte
    Dim aes As New AesCryptoServiceProvider

    Using myAes As Aes = System.Security.Cryptography.Aes.Create()
        myAes.KeySize = 128
        myAes.BlockSize = 128
        myAes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
        myAes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MyEncryptionKey1")
        myAes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MyInitialVector1")

        SymKey = myAes.Key
        IV = myAes.IV
    End Using

    '############
    '## ENCRYPT ROUTING INPUT XML DOC
    '############
    Dim riXml As New XmlDocument
    riXml.Load("C:\routingdoc.xml")        
    aes.Key = SymKey
    aes.IV = IV
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

    ' Convert the plaintext string to a byte array.
    Dim plaintextBytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(riXml.OuterXml.ToString())

    ' Create the stream.
    Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream

    ' Create the encoder to write to the stream.
    Dim encStream As New CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode.Write)

    ' Use the crypto stream to write the byte array to the stream.
    encStream.Write(plaintextBytes, 0, plaintextBytes.Length)
    encStream.FlushFinalBlock()


    '############
    '## PREFIX CIPHER TEXT WITH IV
    '############
    Dim encRiXml() As Byte = ms.ToArray
    Dim arraySize As Integer = IV.Length + encRiXml.Length
    Dim Merged(arraySize) As Byte
    IV.CopyTo(Merged, 0)
    encRiXml.CopyTo(Merged, IV.Length)

    Dim Base64IVEncRiXML As String = Convert.ToBase64String(Merged)

    '******** I BELIVE EVERYTHING PAST HERE IS CORRECT BUT INCLUDED IT TO SHOW WHOLE PROCESS **********

    '############
    '## CREATE SHA1 HASH FOR PLAINTEXT ROUTING INPUT
    '############
    Dim hash() As Byte = New SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(riXml.OuterXml.ToString()))

    '############
    '## CONCATENATE THE SHA1 HASH OF PLAINTEXT ROUTING INPUT XML WITH AES KEY
    '############
    Dim arraySize2 As Integer = hash.Length + SymKey.Length
    Dim Merged2(arraySize2) As Byte
    hash.CopyTo(Merged2, 0)
    SymKey.CopyTo(Merged2, hash.Length)

    '############
    '## ENCRYPT CONCATENATED RESULT USING RSA
    '############
    Dim EncryptionKey As String = File.ReadAllText("C:\cert-1.txt").Replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" & vbCr & vbLf, "").Replace("-----END CERTIFICATE-----", "")

    TextBox1.Text = EncryptionKey

    Dim binaryCertData() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(EncryptionKey)
    Dim cert As X509Certificate2 = New X509Certificate2(binaryCertData)
    Dim xmlKey As String = cert.PublicKey.Key.ToXmlString(False)
    Dim objRSA As RSACryptoServiceProvider = New RSACryptoServiceProvider()
    objRSA.FromXmlString(xmlKey)

    Dim encrypted() As Byte = objRSA.Encrypt(Merged2, False)

    Dim RSAEncryptedSHA1HashAESKey As String = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted)

    postStaticTest(RSAEncryptedSHA1HashAESKey, Base64IVEncRiXML)
End Sub

'PROVIDED SAMPLE OF XML OUTPUT FROM DOCUMENTATION
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
'<SECURE_REQUEST_GROUP>
'<ENCRYPTED_KEY Algorithm=”http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5” >
'bXcCaS97p8TtGzlgZ9ogRcEAaw1D1OQCpk1AQFfWYE5J2CheNtRBpuME+uB3wSkwjIWftkYxQ5JRTQ3Qhz7LrCM+TOORl2lFFTpVC9zGUP1xndfT6EQONViV0XGJieWCzXNyjO3XpEl7IdntkVKucrDN9gA7wlimUdw4Ya5sn08=
'</ ENCRYPTED_KEY>
'< ENCRYPTED_RI Algorithm=”http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc”>
'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
'</ ENCRYPTED_RI>
'</SECURE_REQUEST_GROUP>
```

Comment: Find out if they are using AES with a 128, 192 or 256 bit key (these are the FIPS compliant standard key sizes for AES). A 128 bit IV was specified, but that is standard, all AES uses that size IV since all flavors of AES use a 128 bit block. The rest of the requirements look pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are still a couple open implementation questions (I think I've made clear which ones by the values I used). This absolutely should be refactored, I've done it like this to illustrate how each requirement was met.

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

Public Class SoAnswer
    Dim keySize As Integer = 128
    Public Function EncryptData() As XDocument
        Dim encoder As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding()
        'Specifed Root Name in Declaration
        Dim outputDocument As XDocument = New XDocument(New XElement("SECURE_REQUEST_GROUP"))
        outputDocument.Declaration = New XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "true")
        'outputDocument.Root.Name = "Whatever they specify the root of the xml should be"
        Dim riXml As XDocument
        Dim file As FileStream = New FileStream("C:\routingdoc.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        riXml = XDocument.Load(file)

        Dim symKey As Byte() = Requirement1(keySize)
        Dim encryptedXml As Byte() = Requirement2(encoder.GetBytes(riXml.ToString()), symKey)
        Dim encodedXml = Requirement3(encryptedXml)
        'Moved Requirement 4 below requirement 9 so it will appear below the key in the output XML
        'Requirement4(encodedXml, outputDocument)
        Dim hash As Byte() = Requirement5(riXml)
        Dim hashKey = Requirement6(hash, symKey)
        Dim encryptedHashKey = Requirement7(hashKey)
        Dim encodedHashKey = Requirement8(encryptedHashKey)
        Requirement9(encodedHashKey, outputDocument)
        Requirement4(encodedXml, outputDocument)
        'Now you should have an XDocument with the proper content to POST to the web service

        'Decrypt check
        Dim check As String = encoder.GetString(Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(encodedXml), symKey))

       postStaticTestXML(outputDocument.ToString)
    End Function

    Private Function Requirement1(size As Integer) As Byte()
        Using aes As New AesCryptoServiceProvider()
            aes.KeySize = size
            aes.GenerateKey()
            Return aes.Key
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Function Requirement2(data() As Byte, key() As Byte) As Byte()
        Using aes As New AesCryptoServiceProvider()
            Dim iv As Byte() = aes.IV
            Using encryptor As ICryptoTransform = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv)
                Using msEncrypt As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
                    Using csEncrypt As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                        csEncrypt.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
                        csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock()
                        Dim encryptedData As Byte() = msEncrypt.ToArray()
                        Dim buffer(iv.Length + encryptedData.Length - 1) As Byte
                        buffer = CombineArrays(iv, encryptedData)
                        Return buffer
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Function Requirement3(content As Byte()) As String
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(content)
    End Function

    Private Sub Requirement4(content As String, ByRef doc As XDocument)
    'added XAttribute to accommodate the required algorithm attribute
        doc.Root.Add(New XElement("ENCRYPTED_RI", content, New XAttribute("Algorithm", "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc")))
    End Sub

    Private Function Requirement5(content As XDocument) As Byte()
        Dim encoder As UTF8Encoding = New UTF8Encoding()
        Using hash As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()
            Return hash.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(content.ToString()))
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Function Requirement6(hash As Byte(), key As Byte()) As Byte()
        Return CombineArrays(hash, key)
    End Function

    Private Function Requirement7(content As Byte()) As Byte()
        'I'm assuming here that they originally sent you a .cer file with their private key in it
        'Dim cert As X509Certificate2 = X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile("path\filename of .cer file")
        'X509Certificate2 Could not be directly specified with CreateFromCertFile. A new instance was created and set to derive its value from the retrieved X509Certificate
        Dim cert As X509Certificate2 = New X509Certificate2(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("C:\cert-1.txt"))
        Using rsa As RSACryptoServiceProvider = cert.PublicKey.Key
            'This assumes PKCS7 padding which is most common
            Return rsa.Encrypt(content, False)
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Function Requirement8(content As Byte()) As String
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(content)
    End Function

    Private Sub Requirement9(content As String, ByRef doc As XDocument)
    'Added XAttribute to accommodate for the required "Algorithm" attribute
        doc.Root.Add(New XElement("ENCRYPTED_KEY", content, New XAttribute("Algorithm", "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5")))
    End Sub

    'Support function
    Private Function CombineArrays(array1 As Byte(), array2 As Byte())
        Dim buffer(array1.Length + array2.Length - 1) as Byte
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(array1, 0, buffer, 0, array1.Length)
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(array2, 0, buffer, array1.Length, array2.Length)
        Return buffer
    End Function

    Private Function Decrypt(data() As Byte, key() As Byte) As Byte()
        Dim iv((128 / 8) - 1) As Byte
        Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, iv, 0, iv.Length)
        Dim value(data.Length - iv.Length - 1) As Byte
        Buffer.BlockCopy(data, iv.Length, value, 0, value.Length)
        Using aes As AesCryptoServiceProvider = New AesCryptoServiceProvider()
            Using decryptor As ICryptoTransform = aes.CreateDecryptor(key, iv)
                Using msDecrypt As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(value)
                    Using csDecrypt As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                        Dim decrypted(msDecrypt.Length - 1) As Byte
                        csDecrypt.Read(decrypted, 0, decrypted.Length)
                        Return RemovePadding(decrypted)
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function

    Private Function RemovePadding(data As Byte()) As Byte()
        Dim trimCount As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = data.Length - 1 To data.Length - (128 / 8) + 1 Step -1
            If data(i) = 0 Then trimCount += 1 Else Exit For
        Next

        If trimCount <= 0 Then Return data

        Dim buffer((data.Length - trimCount) - 1) As Byte
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        Return buffer
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: It answers each of the requirements he listed with operational code (once he supplies the root name of the xml to post, which was not specified in the question and the location/name of the .cer file also not specified). I'd say that qualifies as an answer. It is obviously not structured well (as I pointed out at the top) and needs to be refactored. I structured the code this way to make it clear how each requirement is met by the code. How do you get that this is an clarification/extension of the question?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I made some edits to your code to get an operational Secure Request XML. It is however still responding with an Error of "Invalid RI XML encryption" I have listed the sample provided in the documentation at the end of my original question as a reference. What factors do you think would be causing this encryption to fail?

Comment: @Kevin sorry, I was confused and though it was a self-answer by the OP

Comment: I have key size set to 256, did you set it back to 128 as specified in the attribute for that element? < ENCRYPTED_RI Algorithm=”http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc”>. If it is talking about the RSA part of the encryption, there is not anything you can check, you don't have their private key to attempt to decrypt it. You can try to decrypt the AES encrypted part, just use the same symKey, extract the iv and data from the encrypted data and try to decrypt it. If that works it has the be the RAS part and you'll have to work with them to find out what needs to be tweaked.

Comment: I added a couple support methods (Decrypt and RemovePadding) at the end of the code you can use to try testing the AES encryption part.

Comment: Added a line just after the call to Requirement4 to decrypt the encrypted xml so you can check it.

Comment: Changed keySize in the above code to 128 to match the size indicated in the xml attribute specifying the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, Changing the key size to 128 seems to have done the trick. I am now getting past all of the encryption error codes.Thank you so much for your help on this.